# How to remove Windows 7 from alongside with 12.04

Tags: uninstall

I have installed 12.04 alongside Windows 7. Now I am happy with 12.04 that it works better for me. I really want to remove Windows 7 from my HDD and left 12.04 to work with me, and got free HDD space back to 12.04.

Is there an easy way to remove Windows 7 out and keep 12.04 without problem?

Answer (score 3):

I would do the following to remove said partition:

1. Boot a live CD.
2. Select "Try Ubuntu"
3. Open Gparted(Search for it)
4. Make sure your hard disk is selected in the dropdown in the upper right.
5. Right-click the Windows partition and format it to NTFS.
6. Right click your old Windows partition and click Resize/Move. Resize it to an arbitrarily-small size, at least 64MB.
7. Right-click your Ubuntu partition and click Resize/Move
8. Drag the arrows on the left or right as far as possible to make the partition bigger.
9. Click Resize to accept the dialog.
10. Click apply in the toolbar above. The icon is a green check.
11. Acknowledge the warning. Allow the operation to complete, and then open a terminal.
12. Type: `mkdir /mnt/sda2 && sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sda2 /bin/bash`, assuming `sda2` is our Ubuntu partition.
13. Run `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` and then `sudo update-grub`.

Please note that if Ubuntu is in an extended partition, you should right-click and resize the extended partition first.

Comment: If you slide it to the left, and the partition of which the size is increased is the root partition, you'll be left with an unbootable system (it'll be shifting, not resizing). I don't know why, but when I removed openSUSE and extended the Ubuntu root partition, I couldn't boot into Ubuntu either. And I DID complete the partitioning process.

Comment: @AkshitBaunthiyal Thanks for the heads-up. I have found a workaround.

Comment: Did you update grub?

Comment: @ToDo It just isn't my day today. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS - What is it??

Comment: Tried it on VirtualBox. Works. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Of course. Just format the drive in which Windows was installed and run the following command - **sudo update-grub**

You're done. :D

Comment: This leaves a partition in the way.