# How to remove Windows after install WUBI?

Tags: 12.04, wubi

I installed Ubuntu using the Windows installer and I was wondering how to get rid of the old windows install, deleting it and everything with it.

I tried to just install it from my external hard drive but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation two weeks ago.
I found out that the best thing is to do a clean installation of `Ubuntu`.
It seems to be more stable apparently.

Edit: Check this [How to remove Windows 7 from alongside with 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176097/how-to-remove-windows-7-from-alongside-with-12-04)

Comment: would formatting my HDD and attempting to boot from the external be a better option?

Comment: See on the link I have added. Note that I am not an expert or experienced user, but these were comments I received. In the link it has a process to do it.